# Where is CWEB tutorial?

Tags: documentation, cweb

I'm looking into webruby or cweb to write the documentation of my project.

Is there a plugin to eclipse or other gui system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are referring Donald Knuth and Silvio Levy's CWEB system of structured documentation, and you have a TeXLive installation, you can find the CWEB documentation in the `texmf-dist/doc/plain/cweb` directory in your `texlive` tree.

In a standard Linux installation the path is `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/doc/plain/cweb`.

There you will find `cwebman.dvi`, which you can convert to PDF in the standard way:

```
dvips cwebman.dvi
ps2pdf cwebman.ps
```

(You can also try `texdoc cweb` but since there is no PDF it will try to process the DVI directly, which produced errors on my system.)

For the `web2c` system, enter `texdoc web2c`.

EDIT:

Dr. Knuth's original WEB system was for Pascal, but he and Silvio Levy converted it to C, producing CWEB, which you can read about in the cwebman manual described above. Norman Ramsey developed the SPIDER system to allow the WEB concept to be ported theoretically to any combination of a programming language and formatting/display language. See http://www.literateprogramming.com/spider.pdf. So one could write a new version for Ruby or another language.

Regarding editor support: Vim, for one, supports syntax highlighting for CWEB.

Comment: I know is a pascal version. Is ruby version or other scripts systems?

Comment: @bardzo But doesn't Ruby have its own system of automatically generated documentation, RDoc? http://rdoc.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html

Comment: Documentation only API. I would like to documentation process of writing my program , and my decision concepts...

Comment: @bardzo For a model, see Knuth's own progress log for building TeX, `texdoc errorlog`. (Thanks to @SeanAllred)

Comment: Good guess (+1) I retracted my close vote:-)

Comment: For Emacs there is a [mode](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/web/cweb/cweb.el) contributed by Donald Knuth (never tried though).

Comment: You can also do `make fullmanual`, getting the manual **cwebman.pdf**, and the *weaved* documentation for the commands **cweave** (**cweave.dvi**) and **ctangle** (ditto), plus **common.dvi** for the common source code for those two. To get PDFs, you may use **dvipdf**, like `for f in *.dvi; do echo $f; dvipdf $f; done`.